# CodeIgniter Watermarking

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, error-handling, imagelibrary

hi I have a problem with my code

```
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->cat_id = !empty($_POST['cat_id']) ? $_POST['cat_id'] : '';
    $obj->num_chapter = !empty($_POST['num_chapter']) ? $_POST['num_chapter'] : '';
    $obj->tags = !empty($_POST['tags']) ? $_POST['tags'] : '';
    $obj->date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");


    $config['upload_path'] = $this->model_mangachapt->Add($obj);
    $config['encrypt_name'] = false;
    $config['allowed_types'] = "png|jpg|jpeg";
    $config['max_size'] = "1000000";

    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    $img_config['source_image'] = $this->upload->do_multi_upload('userfile');
    $img_config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $img_config['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
    $img_config['wm_overlay_path'] = './images/logo.gif';
    $img_config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'middle';
    $img_config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';

    $this->image_lib->initialize($img_config);
    print $this->image_lib->watermark();
```

I want after is update the image is give the logo off the web.
but if I upload I give me error

the error is:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: imagecolorat() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
Filename: libraries/Image_lib.php
Line Number: 953
```

Comment: If you're using CI, why are you accessing $_POST directly? Also, the error message is pretty straight forward. Where is the call to imagecolorat() being done?

Comment: is a test.

i check the upload image for the watermark but is not working.
but if I do new function is work

Comment: now after I change the code a bit this error:

Severity: Warning

Message: imagecopy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Image_lib.php

Line Number: 948

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is located here

```
$img_config['source_image'] = $this->upload->do_multi_upload('userfile');
```

This function performs the upload of the files, and returns a boolean to check if the upload is successful or not. I does not give the url of an image.

I guess you are using this library for multiple uploads : https://github.com/stvnthomas/CodeIgniter-Multi-Upload

You should instead use the function get_multi_upload_data() to find the correct file to use.